# Hive's freedom of movement rule - can you 'pass over' a gap that you can't go into?

Tags: hive

Imagine the unpassable gap exists in both directions. Can a piece move over it?

I'll just illustrate my question with an example, can the ant move to the tiles marked yellow?

[image: Hive question example]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes,

the ant can move to all spaces marked in yellow. The only restrictions to movement are that it must remain attached to the hive and you can't move into spaces you cannot slide into.

It can cross these "caves" because it continues to be touching the hive when it moves, and that continual touching to the hive (and the sliding rule) are the only requirements.

When moving any piece (but the hopper and when jumping the beetle up onto the hive), it must always remain in contact with at least one tile during the entire movement from beginning to end.

Answer (score 2):

The ant can make this move. It's unclear from the rules around the ant itself, but you can derive it from the description of a spider's movement and the statement in the [FAQ](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Hive_FAQ#toc15) that a spider is strictly weaker than an ant.

Comment: If you aren't convinced, the FAQ also endorses [two online versions](https://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Hive_FAQ#toc0) so you could construct the situation there and see what happens.